# Contract worker - stolen items off site: How to ask for reimbursement

Tags: legal, reimbursement, independent-contractor

I was in Mexico working as a contract employee for a US tool company. 
I went to lunch with one of the workers at the plant I was contracted to work at.
I locked up my back pack with my laptop phone and other items in his trunk.
Thieves broke into his trunk and stole my stuff about $3,000. worth.

I realize I was on my personal time and personal stuff and off site at a restaurant.

I'd like to ask my employer to cover the costs.  What is the best way to approach them about it?

Comment: This will probably come down to the insurance or discretion of your employer.

Comment: §3000 is a lot of money. COmpany stuff? Because otherwise as employer I would ask you why you walk around with pro camera equipment and no insurance or something like that.

Comment: @TomTom macbook+iphone is already around 3000$, you don’t need special camera gear to reach that sum

Comment: Yeah, except if you travel for company I would assume the laptop is owned by the company. And eriously, 3000 is mor elow end cameras. But then, why the **** no proper insurance?

Comment: Just to be clear, the OP is a **contractor**, not an employee of the company they are doing work for.

Comment: If this is your personal equipment check with your insurance carrier for your renter's insurance or home owners insurance.  That is where stuff like this would be covered.  If you do not have this kind of coverage YOU SHOULD.  I use a personal article policy to cover my personal equipment at 100%.  Just make sure if you are using for work they write the policy to cover that.

Comment: Question edited to bring it more in line with site standards.  Falcon, if you feel these edits go against what you are trying to ask please feel free to roll back or edit further.

Comment: Dude, learn about insurances. I have one for my camera equipment. It ALSO covers accidents that would normally be gross neglect (i.e. dropping a lens while on a BOAT if I take the lens of the camera and slip - neglect, but standard in shoots in that scenario). The price is around 3% (!) per year. Heck, i even have a pool insurance - Any equipment I take with me is insured up to avalue X. As a contractor this is business deductble and I am sure a computer etc. insurance is cheaper (way less risk than photo equipment). Contractor, that is YOUR repsonsibility and insurances are handling this.

Comment: Not an answer but put items in the trunk before you get to the restaurant.  When you lock something in the trunk you are announcing this is valuable.  You can ask.

Comment: Basic security tip. As @paparazzo says, you never ever put items on the trunk upon arrival at a place. You put them when you enter the car at the starting of the trip, not in the destination *and even then*. The first rule of security is never putting anything in the car when arriving in the destination, the 2nd rule is never leaving an expensive laptop in a car. Thieves break regularly in easily opened cars and close them again if they do not find valuable items.

Answer (score 15):

You can ask.  The worst thing that will happen is that they say no.

I once had an employer cover costs incurred from a lost passport when travelling for business.  I figured it was a long shot but I pitched the idea as "If I weren't travelling for work this would have been safely locked up in my home" and they agreed.

As a non-Workplace SE point if they don't cover you it's worthwhile checking any insurance that you have to see if it may apply.  My home insurance covers theft of my property even if it isn't stolen from my home.

Comment: Worth noting that even most basic renter insurance will cover theft of items left in car after paying the deductible.That's usually required by most rent controlled places. Be sure to get a police report as they'll want to see that.

Answer (score 3):

You’ll need to check what your insurance covers you for whilst away.

I’m not sure whether locking them in the trunk would have been covered but it’s worth checking. No one will be able to  advise until you've has the conversation with your employer about cover.

Answer (score 3):

> Question can I get my employer who sent me to Mexico to pay for these
>   items?

Most likely, **you are out of luck**.  It's worth a check to see if they have an insurance policy to cover that sort of thing, *but as a contractor* I bet it is up to you to have this type of insurance coverage for your equipment and **not** the company who contracted with you.

*As an employee*, you would need to be familiar with your companies policies and such, but most importantly you would be carrying around the **companies** equipment and not your own.